# Measuring a correction of a stock

Tags: stocks, technical-analysis

I was wondering what the correct way to measure a correction is.

On a weekly chart for example.

If I wanted to measure the % change between 2 weeks.

- Do I measure the difference between the weeks highs?
- Do I measure the difference between the weeks close?
- Something else?

I read a book and the author says:

> The stock should not correct more than 10-15% within 4 weeks.

How do I measure this exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Rate of Change is  based on change in price of the close:

(earlier close - current close) / (current close)

It can also be done on volume, etc.

You can also calculate user defined measurements such as percent change from maximum high price to minimum low price, etc.

Comment: This is kind of what I assumed, so generally people are referring to the close price , unless otherwise specified? Thanks!

Comment: That's a relative change, not a rate of change.  A rate would have time in the denominator.

Comment: @Daniel Cooke - Yes, it is a reference to to the closing price unless otherwise specified.  [Read this](https://www.fidelity.com/learning-center/trading-investing/technical-analysis/technical-indicator-guide/roc)

Comment: @Ben Voigt - Time in the denominator is a different calculation.  Google "Rate Of Change" and get back to me with the definition of this indicator.